# MacBook Air 2017 internal speakers and headphones sound fluctuating - hardware or software issue?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, speakers

Problem:

- My MacBook Air 2017 (OS Mojave) internal speaker is emitting barely audible audio even at max volume.
- When headphones are plugged in, at times the audio suddenly becomes clear of its own accord and at other times does not work at all.
- I had Ubuntu installed for a while (single boot) but then switched back by doing a clean OS Mojave installation. I can't be sure but I think the problem started after that.

Fixes Tried:
I have tried PRAM and SMC reset, checking volume through a test user account and other small fixes listed online.
Can I conclude that its a hardware issue?